# Show connection between 2 minimal polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Let $A$ be a $n$ by $n$ matrix, and $m_A$ the minimal polynomial of $A$.

write down $m_{I-A}$ in terms of $m_A$

I'm stumped honestly. A friend has shown me his solution but I didn't completely understand it, I think he is wrong. But I would like some explanation and how to approach this question.

**Friend's solution**

let $f(x) = m_A(1-x)$:

$*f(I-A) = m_A(I-(I-A)) = m_A(A) = 0$ which implies

$**m_{I-A} | F$ I don't understand why this is correct.

Firstly, I don't understand why * implies **. I agree that * is correct, but why does it mean **? And furthermore...even if it is true that $m_{I-A} | F$ that's still not an answer...

Answer (score 1):

It's a basic result that the minimal polynomial must divide any annihilating polynomial. Indeed, suppose that $p(A) = 0$ and let $m$ denote the minimal polynomial. Through the division algorithm, we can write
$$p(x) = m(x)q(x) + r(x)$$
where $r$ is either $0$ or has degree strictly smaller than $m$. But then
$$0 = p(A) = m(A)q(A) + r(A) = r(A)$$
so that $r(A)$ is also an annihilating polynomial. This forces $r=0$ since otherwise, it would contradict the definition of the minimal polynomial.

Let $f(x) = m_A(1-x)$. Then you've shown that $f(A) = 0$ and therefore $f$ is an annihilating polynomial of $A$. This necessarily means that $m_A\mid f$. But you are correct in that this argument is still incomplete since it's possible that $m_A$ is a proper divisor of $f$.

However, we can complete the argument rather easily. Let $g(x) = m_{I-A}(1-x)$. Then $g(A) = m_{I-A}(I-A) = 0$. Hence we have $$m_A(x)\mid g(x) \implies m_A(1-x)\mid g(1-x)\implies m_A(1-x)\mid m_{I-A}(x)$$
Therefore we've shown that 
$$m_A(1-x) \mid m_{I-A}(x)\ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ \ m_{I-A}(x)\mid m_A(1-x)$$
hence the two polynomials are equal up to multiplication by some unit. Since minimal polynomials are monic, it follows that we have
$$m_{I-A}(x) = (-1)^km_A(1-x)$$
where $k$ is the degree of $m_A$.

Answer (score 1):

One difficulty is that the notation is rather confusing: $m_A(1-x)$ does not mean the product of $m_A$ and $1-x$, but rather the result of substituting $1-x$ for each occurrence of $x$ in $m_A$. To avoid this confusion I will write this substitution as $m_A[x:=1-x]$ instead. One important point is that such a substitution always defines a ring (more precisely $F$-algebra) morphism from $F[x]$ to (in this case) $F[x]$.

By definition $m_{I-A}$ is the minimal degree monic polynomial$~P$ such that $P[x:=I-A]=0$. Now the substitution $x:=I-A$ can be decomposed into two steps: first performing $x:=1-x$ and then performing $x:=A$, in formula $P[x:=I-A]=P[x:=1-x][x:=A]$. Now writing $P_1=P[x:=1-x]$ one has $P[x:=I-A]=P_1[x:=A]$, which is $0$ if and only if $P_1$ is a multiple of $m_A$. So $m_{I-A}$ is a minimal degree monic $P$ such that $P[x:=1-x]$ is a multiple of $m_A$. It is easy to see that the substitution $x:=1-x$ is an invertible morphism $F[X]\to F[X]$, and in fact its own inverse. The inverse image$~J$ of the set (ideal) of multiples of $m_A$ is then the set of multiples of $Q=m_A[x:=1-x]$. Clearly $Q$ itself is a minimal degree nonzero element of$~J$, and it suffices to make this polynomial monic. Since $m_A$ is itself monic, the leading term of $Q$ is $(-x)^d$ where $d=\deg(m_A)$. Then one finds that
$$
  m_{I-A}=(-1)^dm_A[x:=1-x].
$$
In the end, the nature of $A$ is of no importance, just the set of polynomials that is annihilated by the substitution $x:=A$.